# can the Datomic REST API return detailed error messages instead of "Server Error"?

Tags: clojure, datomic, edn

I get an HTTP 500, with the generic message "Server Error", for any erroneous query or transaction submitted to the Datomic REST API.  This occurs for a wide variety of problems: malformed EDN, attribute values with the wrong type, etc.

Is there a setting that enables more detailed error messages?

Comment: If you see [HTTP protocol status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) Datomic shouldn't give you a 5xx error code for malformed requests, that should return a 4xx error. To give detailed information on 5xx errors is up to the server who may disclose further details or may not due privacy or safety reasons and so it would be normally enabled just on dev environments. So it should be something else, not just a bad request, check your instance resources and permissions and its logs.

Comment: @JamesSharp to clarify, the HTTP request is not malformed, just the request's EDN payload string.  This happens for all kinds of internal problems -- it's not a problem in the HTTP layer.

The log has more detailed messages, but I'd like to surface those through the API.